# Incorporating HiPlot and Keras

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, keras, hyperparameter-optimization, hyper-parameters

I just started to learn about Keras and train some models, and I came across HiPlot which is used for tuning hyperparameters. I was wondering if HiPlot can also be used to see what parameters would increase the accuracy of a model in Keras. Some of the parameters that was thinking were: Learning Rate, Batch Size, Dropout Rate, Regularization Strength, Number of Layers, Number of Neurons per Layer, Activation Function, Optimizer Choice.

I am not sure if Keras already provides tools that would help with this, and if using HiPlot it is not going to be as efficient?
Also, is there an automated way to know how the algorithm would perform for different values of parameters?